# How to upgrade Python 3.10 to 3.11 while keeping old packages

Tags: python, pip

I recently upgraded to python 3.11 and i noticed that, since its just a new install of python, i dont get all the packages indecently installed.
How do i manage to install all old packages on the new python version?

Comment: The same way you installed them for 3.10. Package installation is not terribly expensive, either in time or disk space, so you should generally run your code in a project-specific virtual environment that gets freshly provisioned upon creation.

Comment: Assuming this is for a specific project (otherwise why do you need third-party packages?), have you declared your dependencies? Normally you'd create a new virtual environment with the new version and then re-install your dependencies.

Comment: freeze them and reinstall

Comment: @chepner the reason why i ask is because i collect my modules overtime. I don't have a project with ALL the dependencies that i need for every future project. And because i often work offline i dont want to end up with needing a module i once needed but i currently dont have anymore because of the old version of python. Until now i didnt know about `freeze` so that makes it easier

Comment: This might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38469340/1126841

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generate a list of your installed packages

```
pip freeze > packages.txt
```

2. Update Python
3. Install your packages from the file

```
pip install -r packages.txt
```